# Open Camera from fragment using Navigation Component- Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Navigation Component where I have only one activity and multiple fragments and I want to integrate the ML Kit from Google to make an OCR Note App... The issue is how to open the camera ? shall I use Intent ? or something else because I have only one activity. Please do reply.
There is not much information on the internet regarding this and so I had to post this question. please show me a way that would help me learn.
I am using java.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sabir. Please take your time to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then modify your question to meet the guidelines.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.